# How to modify multiple formulas at once in the same way?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm sure this has been asked and answered, but I can't word my question in a way that turns anything up.

I figured out how to filter out certain characters from the data I receive by editing the formulas like this:

```
='Sheet1'!$B$4
```

becomes

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE('Sheet1'!$B$4,"(",""),")",""),"N",""),"E",""),"S",""),"W",""),"m","")
```

What this does is remove any of those six characters from the cell. Note that the new formula contains the original formula within.

I need to apply this change to all of the formulas in the sheet, and there are a lot of them. I tried playing around with `flash-fill`; no luck. Is there an easier way to "add" those substitute commands to all of the formulas without editing them all by hand?

Thanks

EDIT: This was the macro I ended up making, and it worked:

```
Sub Macro1()
Dim CurrentCell As String
  CurrentCell = ActiveCell.Formula
  CurrentCell = Replace("=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(@,""("",""""),"")"",""""),""N"",""""),""E"",""""),""S"",""""),""W"",""""),""m"","""")", "@", Mid(CurrentCell, 2))
  ActiveCell.Formula = CurrentCell
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the data that you have in Sheet1B4? What do you want to change that to ? after applying this substitute formula?

Comment: if your formulas are in one column just put the new formula in a different column that then refers to the ouput of the first and drag down.

Comment: @Gowtham Shiva the data in that sheet is irrelevant, I'm just trying to add the seven substitution commands to every cell. Note that 'Sheet1'!$B$4 is still in the edited formula.

Comment: @CRBTC Why do you use a substitute function on an irrelevant data?

Comment: @Scott Craner unfortunately the spreadsheet is not as well structured as I would like and I cannot change the arrangement of the cells as another spreadsheet depends on the values of this one.

Comment: @Gowtham Shiva The data is relevant to my work, just irrelevant to what I am trying to do. What I'm trying to do is replace **X** with =SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(**X**,"(",""),")",""),"N",""),"E",""),"S",""),"W",""),"m","") in every cell on the spreadsheet.

Comment: To do this in place you will need vba.  You could easily do this and link it to a short cut key that will work on the selected cells.

Comment: @Scott Craner I'll give that a shot and report back. Thanks.

Comment: Please mark your answer as accepted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the macro I ended up making, and it worked!

```
Sub Macro1()
Dim CurrentCell As String
  CurrentCell = ActiveCell.Formula
  CurrentCell = Replace("=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(@,""("",""""),"")"",""""),""N"",""""),""E"",""""),""S"",""""),""W"",""""),""m"","""")", "@", Mid(CurrentCell, 2))
  ActiveCell.Formula = CurrentCell
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe if you highlight the range of cells containing the formulas you want to update then edit the first of those cells (top left) then use control enter, rather than just enter it will update all the formulas in the highlighted range.